# PHP Script: works in Safari, but not Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, safari

I get this message from running a php script in Chrome browser:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/smilep6/public_html/php/fm_read.php
```

The path to the script is:

```
http://website.com/php/fm_read.php
```

I am not a coder so do not know why it works in Safari and not Chrome.

Thanks in advance for your help - Sam

Comment: Show the code that causes this issue. BTW, PHP does not run in-browser.

Comment: Wrong: your PHP script doesn't care about Chrome or Safari or IE or Firefox, nor does your PHP run in a web browser: it simply sends output through the web server to whichever browser requests it

Answer (score 0):

The inconsistency between Safari and Chrome is most likely a browser caching issue where safari is showing the last good response that it received.  If you hard refresh the safari and chrome windows they should both display the same thing.  Browsers get very touchy when servers send back HTTP error codes and can deal with erroneous responses strangely.

As far as the actual error we cannot help without some of the code snippets and background information.

Comment: This php script consists of 3 php files that connect to a Filemaker WebDirect web page. Listing all the scripts will probably just muddy the waters because the php script also runs a script in Filemaker. I am just trying to figure out what the absolute path would be to the php scripts. Presently, I have http:website.com/php/fm_link.php that connects to fm_read.php and fm_write.php. The error shows that no such file in /home/smilep6/public_html/php/fm_read.php. So how do I create an absolute link the includes the /home/smilep6/public_html/....... ?

Comment: Ah look into the `dirname()` function and the __ FILE __ constant.  they will help you use PHP includes with absolute paths.  Example: `include( dirname(__FILE__) . '/fm_write.php' )`

Comment: If that doesn't help I would really need to see some excerpts of `/home/smilep6/public_html/php/fm_read.php` to be able to debug further